# Worksheet_SelectionChange Returns an error if the condition is false

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, selectionchanged

I try to bounce a Form
**if** the selection is in column 4 **and** only 1 cell is selected **and** the cell next in column 3 is empty

If the condition is true it works

But if the condition is false, an error comes out:

> run time error '13': type mismatch,

On the if line

That's the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Offset(, -1).Value = 0 Then

    C = Target.Offset(, -1).Address
    UserForm1.Show

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.Offset(,-1).Value = 0` will fail if `Target` is a multi-cell range, so nest that `If` instead of using `And`.

Comment: Thanks,
Great solution

Comment: Also, safer to use `CountLarge` instead of `Count`, and you can just drop the `Cells`: `Target.CountLarge = 1`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Selection Change Disaster

**The Two to Three Issues**

You should use `CountLarge` instead of `Count`. If you select too many cells, `Count` will cause `Run-time error '6': Overflow`. Try it by selecting all cells on the worksheet (`CTRL+A`).

If you select a range in column `A`, the impossibility of calculating `Target.Offset(, -1)` will cause 
`Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`.

If multiple cells are selected then `Target.Offset(,-1).Value` will result in an array which can not be compared to `0` which will cause `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`.

**A possible solution**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const ColumnNumber As Long = 4
    Const ColumnOffset As Long = -1
    Const OffsetValue As Long = 0

    Dim C As String

    With Target
        If .Column + ColumnOffset < 1 Or .Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If .Column = ColumnNumber And .Offset(, ColumnOffset) = OffsetValue Then
            C = Target.Offset(, ColumnOffset).Address
            UserForm1.Show
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```